# Create a PDA that accepts the following language

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I need to create a PDA that accepts by empty stack and accepts the language formed by strings over the alphabet $\{a, b\}$ of the form: $uw$, where $w$ is the string $u$ reversed and doubled. So, for example, if $u=ab$ then $w=bbaa$ (the $ab$ is reversed then its characters are doubled).

Examples of strings in the language: $\epsilon$, $aaa$, $baaabb$, $abbbbbbaa$, etc.

I'm really struggling with setting up a PDA that satisfies the criteria. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please tell if there are any conditions on string u and w... it would be better if you define the language than give an example of it for a comprehensive answer

Comment: $u$ can be any string made up of $a$'s and $b$'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDA operates as follows :

1. Push the symbols you read to the stack
2. Non-deterministically guess when u ends and w starts
3. Now for the rest of the string , we consider 2 symbols by 2 symbols , if the 2 symbols are not the same reject , if the 2 symbols are the same , compare them to top of stack , if they are not the same symbol reject , if they are the same pop the stack
4. After reading the entire input , if the stack is empty accept , else reject

Ex : s = ab bbaa , we push a,b to stack , then we guess u ends and w starts , now we read  b , then b , both are same symbol , we look at top of stack we have  b we pop the b , now the stack has a , and we will read aa , repeat the above again and we accept

If you get how it works , you may want to try to sketch the PDA

Here is a sketch of the PDA to check your answer  :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is very helpful. I'm still struggling to put it all together but I'm getting there. Your use of the symbol #, I'm assuming that's equivalent to the use of $Z_{0}$ used in my textbook to denote the empty stack?

Comment: Yes , some books use Z0 and some use $$ , but you should remember that any special symbol can be used to do this check , by special we mean that it is in Γ but not in Σ , and is only used to do the check (these conditions guarantee that no problem occurs)  , however Z0 is preferable since some languages contain # or $ , so in this PDA feel free to replace # by Z0  , if you have any other questions please feel free to ask